# Using free on a struct that contains a pointer to unsigned ints array, fills the array with data

Tags: c, malloc, free

(Simplified version of my problem, developing in netbeans)
I have this struct defined:

```
typedef struct data_info
{
    unsigned int* array; //containing ints at hex base
    int x;
}data;
```

And in main function I am doing these:

```
data *d = malloc(sizeof(data);
d->array = malloc(4*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

After the use of this struct I want to deallocate the memory. I am watching the variables state with netbeans debug:

```
address of (d->array) -> 0x605670
free(d->array); //makes the array NULL
d->array = NULL;
free(d); //makes the pointer not NULL - adress is 0x605500
```

And also the array state is this (hex values):

> d->array[0] = 0
>   d->array[1] = 0
>   d->array[2] = 31
>   d->array[3] = 0

Why does the d->array get an address value?

Comment: This description is a little confusing.  By "address of d->array", do you literally mean "the location of `d->array`", or do you mean "the location of the dynamically-allocated memory pointed to by `d->array`"?  Also, `free(d->array)` should not modify `d->array`, nor should it modify the memory used for the array itself; it is unlikely to "make the array NULL"...  Could you perhaps this experiment, but using `printf` statements instead of the debugger, and then post the code here?  That way, we'll know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You are right, I'm sorry. With "address of d->array" I mean the content of this variable. What would you want me to do?

Comment: free(d->array) and d->array = NULL implies you are freeing the address pointed by d->array. Indexing into the address pointed by d->array is invalid after freeing it.